# Calling a html from javascript at at a particulare level of function

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first post, so I'll try to make it as clear as possible. I could not find the answer on the forum so I might not be looking with proper key words..

I am trying to make an adventure game. For that I have:

- an index.html that calls a js function (working good)
- this js function displays the different chapters (working good)
- At chapter 5, the js function calls another HTML (working good): a memory game with its own js function.(working good)
- At the end of the game, there is a button /js function that sends me to a new HTML file at chapter 6. (working good)

So I have 2 HTML files (with its own JS file): one for chapter 1 to 5, and from chapter 6 to 10.
Ideally, I wanted to have only one HTML with all the chapters : 1 to 10, and so I was trying to figure out how to call my initial HTML file but directly at chapter 6 from the js of the memory game, if I were to combine them together, So I do not repeat the same js code twice.

I hope that makes sense to somebody.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Lulue

Comment: Use localStorage like: `localStorage.setItem('memory', 'passed');`. When you load your main game, do `if (localStorage.getItem('memory')) /* jump to chapter 6 */`

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help !!! I was able to make it work by using "sessionStorage" instead of "localStorage". For some unknown reasons, the data were stored but then not saved from one html to another... even though they were in the same brownser.  Anyway, it's working, so I'm just sharing that info in case someone else got the same problem with localStorage.

Comment: Weird, it has always worked with using localStorage for me.